# change default property setter visibility for vs2015 quick actions (c#)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

VS2015's Quick Actions will let you generate a property when you try to set a class level variable that does not exist:

[image: Make a property!]

However, by default these have private setters:

[image]

While I understand the intent of this, it causes problems for anything which tries to automatically set the variables, such as MVC's Model Binding, and it's easy to forget to remove them and a pain to track down the "bug".

*How can I change this default behavior?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code snippet:

> ..\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\propg.snippet

Comment: Aw... looked plausible but unfortunately that didn't do the trick.  I even restarted visual studio.  The 'propg' shortcut was updated but the auto-generated code from the Quick Action was not.

Comment: Yes. You are right. This snippet is executed when entering "propg". There seems to be no documented way to configure the quick action template.